# Zero margins with memoir

Tags: errors, margins, memoir

I am trying to set up custom page size with zero margins. Here is the example

```
\documentclass[oneside,final,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for sample text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}

\setstocksize{194.73mm}{132.76mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.55mm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0mm}{*}{*}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setheadfoot{0mm}{0mm}
\setheaderspaces{*}{0mm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0mm}{0mm}{0mm}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\chapter*{First Chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This does not compile (with pdflatex), the error is

```
! Class memoir Error: \footskip (0.0pt) is too large for \lowermargin (-8.9395pt) by 8.9395pt.
```

I explicitly set header/footer to empty, how come it tries(?) to put something there and gets negative lowermargin?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by default memoir actually does not give you the text height you ask for, instead it choose the one that is closest and is an integral number of lines high.

In your case you need to switch the algorithm by using

```
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]
```

Comment: @AlexV: It does? When I copy & paste your document to an empty file and add the `[fixed]`, pdflatex will give me: `ERROR: Class memoir Error: \marginparsep is zero or negative.`

Comment: @Thomas: Yes it does. I use MikTex 2.9 with the latest updates.